# JSON query matching

Tags: json

For the given input JSON:

```json
{
  "person": {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 25
  },
  "status": {
    "title": "assigned",
    "type": 3
  }
}
```

I need to build a string query that I could use to answer if the given JSON matches it or not. For example **if the given person's name is "John" and his age is in the range of 20..30 and his status is not 4**.
I need the query to be presented as a string and a commonly known library that can run it. I need it on multiple platforms (iOS, Android, Xamarin). I've tried JSON Path and JSON schemas, but didn't really figure out if it's able to achieve that with them. JSON Path seems to be specified on finding a single value in the JSON by a certain condition and JSON Schema mostly checks for the data structure and types.

Comment: Why not just parse it?

Comment: @GuruStron I expect queries to be dynamic and the input JSON to change over time. I'd prefer not to change the parsing algorithm every time, but rather having a dynamic solution. Like when the input JSON structure changes, I can just update the queries to match the new structure and values.

Comment: if you don't know a structure nothing will work.

Comment: @Serge it will since both the input JSON and the query string are gonna be generated by the code on the API. But it wasn't a question if it's gonna work or not. I basically asked if there's a library that can evaluate such queries. I guess I found that I can use JSON schema with regex patterns for it.

Comment: You can just use parse as @GuruStron advised , it is more simple  and more reliable then your answer below

Answer (score -1):

Ok, found the solution. If I format the whole input object as a single-element array like that:

```json
[
    {
      "person": {
        "name": "John",
        "age": 25
      },
      "status": {
        "title": "assigned",
        "type": 3
      }
    }
]
```

That will allow me to use JSON Path expressions:

```
$[?(@.person.name == 'John' && @.person.age >= 20 && @.status.type != 4)]
```

Basically if it doesn't match there won't be a result.